# How to upgrade pip in Microsoft Azure from 1.5.6 to 9.0.1?

Tags: python, azure, pip, azure-web-app-service

I am deploying a flask web app to Azure, and need to upgrade pip on Azure to the latest version. I have tried running

```
 D:\python34\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

in the Kudu console of Azure, but this didn't work, and gave me an error below.

```
Access is denied: 'd:\\python34\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-1.5.6.dist-info\\description.rst'
```

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You need the right user rights to execute, or a virtual environment to run your stuff

Comment: @user1767754 Thanks! How can I obtain that right in Azure/Kudu environment to be specific? Would appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the right method here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41843617/9005590

I logged in to Kudu console at Azure so that I can edit the deploy.cmd file, and added

```
env\scripts\python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 1):

For upgrading the Python version, please try the following manually steps:

•   Navigate to Azure portal

•   Click on App Service blade of Web App, select Extensions and then Add.

•   From the list of extensions, scroll down until you spot the Python logos, then choose the version you need and let us know how this goes.

Comment: More details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service