# How can I upgrade pip (Local Git, App Service) to a specific version and then make the Oryx use that pip?

Tags: python, azure-web-app-service

I am unable to find a clear answer on this.

I thought this would be clear-cut described at least somewhere (no jargon, just plain logic).

I have read a number of articles without no success so far. I scavenged probably 20 different articles all over the place. They either do not apply or there is lack of parity with who is seeing what in their portal.

Things I have read about:

- Using environment variables in the form App Settings [ does not work as it does not appear to apply to the pip that Oryx ultimately ends up using ]
- Using .deployment file with a mention of build.cmd (bash file) to upgrade pip [ does not appear to work due to the same reason ]

All I want is properly bootstrap my application. I believe, in this case, that would mean to make sure the pip is upgraded, and Oryx subsequently uses that pip to install dependencies via requirements.txt; instead, an older pip is used, and installation fails for certain dependencies.

I do not know what is ideal in this case:

- Figure out a Kudu solution
- Figure out a Oryx solution (I assume this)
- Bypass deployment altogether and just copy the entire structure from the local disk
- Figure out some Docker solution

The fact that Oryx tries to build automatically is great and I want to preferably go by that route.

Platform - Linux
Python - 3.6.15
Required version of pip - 21.3.1

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade pip version in Azure App Service:

1. Navigate to `env\scripts\python` in KUDU site of your Azure App Service, run the command  `-m pip install --upgrade pip`.
2. As @[Shu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47501563/19991670) mentioned, add below command in `deploy.cmd` file before install requirements.txt command:

> `env\scripts\python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

I have deployed a Python App to Azure App Service using Local Git.

```
C:\Users\uname\pyapp>git push azure master

Enumerating objects: 1493, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1493/1493), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1478/1478), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1493/1493), 6.19 MiB | 213.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1493 (delta 81), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (81/81), done.
remote: Deploy Async
remote: Updating branch 'master'.
remote: ..
remote: Updating submodules.
remote: Preparing deployment for commit id '26fdf1d11b'.
remote: PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False
remote: PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot
remote: Repository path is /home/site/repository
remote: Running oryx build...
remote: Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
remote: You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues
remote:
remote: Oryx Version: 0.2.20230508.1, Commit: 7fe2bf39b357dd68572b438a85ca50b5ecfb4592, ReleaseTagName: 20230508.1
remote:
remote: Build Operation ID: 1d2755d6564ce8d3
remote: Repository Commit : 26fdf1d11bea255c3ad0d0a1d209536fc1c18ee5
remote: OS Type           : bullseye
remote: Image Type        : githubactions
remote:
remote: Detecting platforms...
remote: .
remote: Detected following platforms:
remote:   python: 3.11.7
remote: Version '3.11.7' of platform 'python' is not installed. Generating script to install it...
remote:
remote: Using intermediate directory '/tmp/8dc344b10a25ba0'.
remote:
remote: Copying files to the intermediate directory...
remote: ...
remote: Done in 8 sec(s).
remote:
remote: Source directory     : /tmp/8dc344b10a25ba0
remote: Destination directory: /home/site/wwwroot
remote:
remote:
remote: Downloading and extracting 'python' version '3.11.7' to '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.11.7'...
remote: Detected image debian flavor: bullseye.
remote: Downloaded in 1 sec(s).
remote: Verifying checksum...
remote: Extracting contents...
remote: performing sha512 checksum for: python...
remote: Done in 6 sec(s).
remote:
remote: image detector file exists, platform is python..
remote: OS detector file exists, OS is bullseye..
remote: Python Version: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.11.7/bin/python3.11
remote: Creating directory for command manifest file if it does not exist
remote: Removing existing manifest file
remote: Python Virtual Environment: antenv
remote: Creating virtual environment...
remote: Activating virtual environment...
remote: Running pip install...
remote: [08:40:42+0000] Collecting flask (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))

//removed few logs

remote: Build Summary :
remote: ===============
remote: Errors (0)
remote: Warnings (0)
remote:
remote: Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
remote: Deployment successful. deployer =  deploymentPath =
remote: Deployment Logs : 'https://kpywebapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui/jsonviewer?view_url=/api/deployments/26fdf1d11bea255c3ad0d0a1d209536fc1c18ee5/log'
To https://kpywebapp.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/kpywebapp.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

To upgrade pip version in the Python Linux Azure App Service, followed below steps:

- In the KUDU site of the App Service(https://appname.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui)=> open `WebSSH or Bash`.
- Check if you can see virtual environment(***venv***) folder,
  navigate to `env/Scripts` in the SSH and run the command `python -m pip install --upgrade pip==<required_version>`:

[image]